# Prepared statements and auto_increment error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table, looks like this

```
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name  | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username   | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password   | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

I've tried to use prepared statements for my registration system:

```
$sql = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
$sql->bind_param('sssss', $first, $last, $email, $username, $pwd);
$sql->execute();
```

But I am getting this error : 
Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean.

I removed the 'id' column and now it works fine.

How can I use prepared statements with the 'id' column in my table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

`$sql = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, username, password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");`

This should work even if you add the `id` column back into your table. It should also work without it.

Since the first column is to be ignored, you have to specify which columns you are inserting into. The first column does not get ignored just because you called it `id`, or just because it is `auto_increment`. SQL will do what you tell it to, and it just assumes that the first parameter you give it is supposed to go in the first column of the table.

Often times, queries are written like the above, including the table names, so that something doesn't break in the event that someone modifies the table for some reason. Granted, you shouldn't have random modifications in a production situation either way, but you get the idea.

Keep in mind that the columns need to be specified in the same order as you're planning on inserting them.